# navigation drawer ArrayList

Tags: kotlin, navigation-drawer

I have downloaded this project, navigation drawer from github, https://github.com/ranger163/SlidingMenuNavigation, which I can not get with the onclick I will have the desired fragment, can you help me please?

This is what I do in NainActivity:

```
private fun updateDrawerItems(screenState: ScreenState<MainActivityState>?) {
        when (screenState) {
            is ScreenState.Render -> setDrawerItems(screenState.renderState, position = 0)
        }
    }

    private fun setDrawerItems(renderState: MainActivityState, position: Int) {
        when (renderState) {
            is MainActivityState.ShowNavItems -> {
                navRecycler.apply {
                    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
                    adapter = NavAdapter(renderState.navItems, viewModel::onNavItemClicked)
                }
            }
            is MainActivityState.HandleNavItemClick -> {

                    when (position) {
                        0 -> fragmentTransaction(DivFragment())
                        1 -> fragmentTransaction(BuscarFragment())
                    }

                toast("ItemClicked")
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
        }
    }
```

but on the line

```
is ScreenState.Render -> setDrawerItems(screenState.renderState, position = 0)
```

cannot be position = number
Any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution *If-else

```
  is MainActivityState.HandleNavItemClick -> {
                        if (renderState.navItem.name == "String"){
                            fragmentTransaction(BuscarFragment())
                        }
```